# How to get one container from another container?

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have a container that includes many items and some of those items are containers. 
And I need to get those **internal containers**. What is the best practice fot that?

My solution is kinda ugly for me :(

```
container a = [1, 2, ["one","two","three"]];
container b;
int i;
;

for (i = 1; i <= conLen(a); i++)
{
    try
    {
        b = conPeek(a, i);
        info(strFmt("%1", conPeek(b,1)));//here should be some logic with b items
    }
    catch
    {
         info(strFmt("NOT A CONTAINER %1",  conPeek(a, i)));
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was really easy. But maybe it will be helpfull for someone in the future.

```
  if(typeOf(conPeek(a, i)) == Types::Container)
  {
        b = conPeek(a, i);
        info(strFmt("%1", conPeek(b,1)));
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Please try the following

```
...
if (typeof(conPeek(a, i)) == Types::Container)
{
    info("It's a container");
}
...
```